# ajax query error on callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, jquery

```
$(this).find(':submit').attr('disabled',true);
        $.ajax(
        {
            url:'/enviarSugerenciaMessageBoard',
            cache: false,
            type: 'POST',
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function(success)
            {
                if(success=='Envio correcto')
                {
                    console.log('Envio correcto');
                    $(this).find(':submit').attr('disabled',false);
                }else{
                    console.log('Error en el envio');
                    $(this).find(':submit').attr('disabled',false);
                }
            }
        });
```

this ajax query works fine the problem is when i get 'Envio correcto' from server, in console i get Envio correcto but the attr disabled false dont work...

i try to make other functions on success like append or prepend but didnt work

even in async:false

Comment: `this` inside callback refers to the ajax object, not the `this` you had earlier. Also, I would suggest you to use `prop()` instead of `attr()` to `disable` elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `this` keyword is not belong that element anymore in success function. You should backup this variable to another variable, than you can use it.

Like this,

```
$(this).find(':submit').attr('disabled',true);
var self = this;
        $.ajax(
        {
            url:'/enviarSugerenciaMessageBoard',
            cache: false,
            type: 'POST',
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function(success)
            {
                if(success=='Envio correcto')
                {
                    console.log('Envio correcto');
                    $(self).find(':submit').attr('disabled',false);
                }else{
                    console.log('Error en el envio');
                    $(self).find(':submit').attr('disabled',false);
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

Inside the `success` callback, `this` is not what it was from where you called `.ajax()`. To control the value of `this` inside the callback, you can use the `context` option in `.ajax()`

In your case, all you need to do is:

```
$.ajax({
    context: this, // what you wnat `this` to be inside success
    url:'/enviarSugerenciaMessageBoard',
    ...
    success: function(success) {
        // 'this' is what you passed in via context
    });
```

Docs: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ - Scroll down to see the `context` option

Comment: Thats what I love about SO. You always learn new things. Thanks for `context` :)